# Cannot accurately convert from long format to wide in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, spread

I am trying to convert from long format to wide with following code.

```
 data_ige<-read.csv("serology.csv",header = TRUE,na.strings=0)
```

library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data_new <- data_ige %>% spread(test, value)

I have following dataset
[existing dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlvBo.png)

After running the code, it transforms the date (but not in the way i want) as seen in the next image, items highlighted in yellow show that these values are coming in multiple rows but they should be in first row instead of a new row. each patient had  data either for 1 visit  or 2 visit. so all test results from 1 visit, i want to see them in one row and test results from visit 2 in second row.

[After transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el5Vf.png)

This screen shot shows the desired outcome.

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axb5g.png)

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example instead of image.  Have you tried `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df1), ID +date ~ test, value.var = 'value')`

Comment: Based on the image, may be you need `data_ige %>% group_by(id, date, test) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% ungroup %>% spread(test, value)`

Comment: Hi@akrun, I applied your code but unfortunately it did not work for me the number of observations remain same. I applied both codes.

Comment: I created the example based on the image showed and it is working for me in solutioin below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a sequence column as there are duplicates

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_ige %>% 
   group_by(ID, date, test) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   spread(test, value) %>%
   #or use pivot_wider as spread is getting deprecated
   #  pivot_wider(names_from = test, values_from = value) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 8 x 9
#  ID     date    `1`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`
#  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A      2008  0.035 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#2 A      2011  2.75  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#3 B      2011  9.99   3.65  0.68  0.02  0.17  0.5  NA   
#4 C      2008  0     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#5 C      2011 NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0.09
#6 D      2008  0      0     0     0     0     0.59  0   
#7 D      2011  0      0.49  0.2   0.08  0.16  0.5   0.13
#8 D      2011  9.99  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
data_ige <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), date = c(2008, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2008, 2011, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011), test = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), value = c(0.035, 2.75, 9.99, 
3.65, 0.68, 0.02, 0.17, 0.5, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.59, 
0, 9.99, 0.49, 0.2, 0.08, 0.16, 0.5, 0.13)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine for me when I use the table you link to. There might be an issue with your data, i.e. you may have imported strings as factors or some such. Try it with the data I provide below:

```r
data_ige %>% spread(test, value)

#### OUTPUT ####

  ID date     1    3    4    5    6    7    8
1  A 2008 0.035   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2  A 2011 2.750   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3  B 2011 9.990 3.65 0.68 0.02 0.17 0.50 0.09
4  C 2008 0.000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5  C 2011 0.000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6  D 2008 0.000 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.59 0.00
7  D 2011 9.990 0.49 0.20 0.08 0.16 0.50 0.13
```

One thing you might want to do is add a row for `test == 2`, which isn't in your data. That way you'll get a column `2` with only `NA`s, just like the image of the data frame you link to:

```r
data_ige %>%
    add_row(ID = "A", date = 2008, test = 2) %>% 
    spread(test, value)

#### OUTPUT ####

  ID date     1  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
1  A 2008 0.035 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2  A 2011 2.750 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3  B 2011 9.990 NA 3.65 0.68 0.02 0.17 0.50 0.09
4  C 2008 0.000 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5  C 2011 0.000 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6  D 2008 0.000 NA 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.59 0.00
7  D 2011 9.990 NA 0.49 0.20 0.08 0.16 0.50 0.13
```

Here's the data frame I used:

```r
data_ige <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D"), date = c(2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2008L, 2011L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L), test = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
    value = c(0.035, 2.75, 9.99, 3.65, 0.68, 0.02, 0.17, 0.5, 
    0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.59, 0, 9.99, 0.49, 0.2, 0.08, 
    0.16, 0.5, 0.13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Comment: Hi @LaLa, I do not know the reason but it did not work for me I have 6253 rows in my dataset and when I apply rows remain the same. Would you please suggest what should I check?

Comment: @bushra can you use `dput(data_ige[sample.int(nrow(data_ige), 50),])` to give us a sample of your data? Just paste the output (starts with `structure(...`) in your original question.

Comment: structure(list(ID = c(628L, 6028L, 5441L, 3823L, 4038L, 859L, 
6158L, 2306L, 6284L, 5175L, 2769L, 3612L, 6209L, 6245L, 1523L, 
6542L, 3314L, 1675L, 2141L, 2608L, 1937L, 5281L, 4787L, 3804L, 
647L, 846L, 1229L, 3185L, 2110L, 2402L, 5346L, 657L, 162L, 5116L, 
2952L, 981L, 1439L, 1607L, 1193L, 2467L, 6160L, 2669L, 3582L, 
5422L, 2124L, 4418L, 2469L, 4052L, 747L, 5140L), EPID = c(4900213L, 
200372L, 501602L, 500259L, 1801101L, 501204L, 200499L, 3901166L, 
200625L, 4801248L, 500050L, 4800935L, 200545L, 200559L, 4800631L,

Comment: the outcome is very long and i can't paste that here. this is just the brief section I pasted.

Comment: @bushra you should add the output `structure(…)` to your original question, not the comments.